# Background Image overlaps Refresh Control

Tags: ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

In xcode 7.1, I have used the refresh control feature of a TableView.
I have also used the following code to set an image to the background

```
UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[tempImageView setFrame:self.tableView.frame];
self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
```

This image overlaps the activity indicator on the app so you can't see if its working. Is there a way to put the activity indicator back on top?

Thanks

Comment: An easier approach would be to simply put you `UIImageView` behind the `UITableView` and not use the `backgroundView` property.

Comment: would you give an image to clarify the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this line

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor =
  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

Instead of using

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
```

Note: **but your `UIImage` size should be greater/equal to `UITableView` size**